# How to access a global service function within a twig extension using Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'd like to have a global function which is available in all controllers as well as in a twig extension.
The function currently looks like this:

```
namespace Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller {

/**
 * Check if the user is assigned to one of the given airlines
 *
 * @param Array $airlines
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function HAS_AIRLINE(Array $airlines) {
    if ($airlines == null)
        return false;

    // Get current user
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    foreach ($airlines as $airline) {
        if($user->hasAirline($airline))
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I implemented this function into the BaseController.php, so I can use it in all other controllers. This works perfectly fine so far.
Now I want to use this function in a twig extension as well, but I don't know how. I do have the following function in my twig extension:

```
/* 
 * Check if the current user has one of the given roles by using the function provided by the base controller
 */
public function hasAirline($airlines= Array())
{
    if($airlines == null)
        return false;

    // How can I now use the function from my BaseController?
    return HAS_AIRLINE($airlines);
}
```

I already tried to define the BaseController as a service and use the service in the twig extension, but I couldn't manage that.

Could someone please help me? I feel like there is something I did not understand about Symfony yet, but the docs do not really help me.

Thank you,
MRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the logic in your `User` entity:

```
class User
{
    public function hasAirline($airlines)
    {
        foreach ($airlines as $airline)
        {
            if ($this->getAirlines()->contains($airline))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This will work if `getAirlines()` return an `ArrayCollection` from Doctrine2, this allow the use of the [`contains()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#_contains) method.

Then you can use this in the controller:

```
public function HAS_AIRLINE(Array $airlines) {
    return $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()
        ->hasAirline($airlines);
}
```

Or in Twig with [`app.user`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-in-a-template):

```
{{ set hasAirline = app.user.hasAirline(airlines) }}
```